# Como Formatear de números a monedas En Android estudio Java

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, jdbc

Tengo este Código, pero al momento de Formatearlo el numero a moneda o numero con decima no lo convierte. ejemplo en mi App aparece 1.0105 y pretendo que salga con los el entero y con 2 decimales o dependiendo del resultado de la BD si es entero. Les comparto el código Fuente, estoy trabajando con jtds jdbc

Driver. Les agradecería de sus Gran apoyo.

Mainactivity.java

```
 EditText dni,cb,clave,cat,uni,precious,alpla;

precious = findViewById(R.id.lblprec);

 precious.setText(rs.getString(8));
```